# Angular 2+ get specific value on selected value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the following Angular 2+ code, I have an Array in TypeScript:

```
models = [{idModele: 1, model: "Bianca", price: 500}, {idModele: 2, model: "etc", price: 600} ]
```

I would like to know, how it's done so that when I choose a specific model, I automatically receive its price in < p > balise or something else.

Here is my HTML Example:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="modeles" formControlName="modeles">
                    <option selected>Choisir...</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let modele of modeles">{{ modele.modele }}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: What you mean by "_I automatically receive its price in < p > balise or something else._"?

Comment: @palaѕн I mean when I choose for example a model called " Bianca ", it's give me it's price from the same array :) 

Like the example we have the model called " Bianca " and it's price is 500.

Comment: This code having problem of reading models. you have used "models' in typescript and your are looping with "modeles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily:

Just add `app.component.ts` code like:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  selectedPrice:Number
  models:Array<Object> = [
      {idModele: 1, model: "Bianca", price: 500}, 
      {idModele: 2, model: "etc", price: 600} 
  ] 
}
```

and add `app.component.html` code like:

```
<h1>Selecting Model</h1>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedPrice">
  <option *ngFor="let model of models" [ngValue]="model.price">
    {{model.model}}
  </option>
</select>

<hr>

<p>{{ selectedPrice }}</p>
```

Comment: Yeah ! it's working ! it was my fault, I pasted " price " in english and my project is in french ^^ " prix "

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below Code.

HTML Code:

```
    <select class="form-control" id="modeles" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <option *ngFor="let model of models" [value]="model.price">{{ model.name }}</option>
</select>

<p>{{selectedValue}}</p>
```

Typescript Code:

```
 selectedValue: number;
  models = [
    { idModele: 1, name: "Bianca", price: 500 },
    { idModele: 2, name: "etc", price: 600 }
  ];
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work :/

I got :    " Cannot read property 'price' of undefined "

Comment: Did you tried code what I have pasted? Use code which I have given. Your code having problem with name that you are using.

Comment: Yes and i got this result [link](https://i.imgur.com/7zU3ltk.png)

Comment: Yeah ! it's working ! it was my fault, I pasted " price " in english and my project is in french ^^ " prix "

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

in html

```
<select . . .  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"> 
    <option *ngFor="let model of models" [value]="model?.price">{{model.name}}</option> 
</select> 

{{selectedValue}}
```

in ts

```
selectedValue: number;
  models = [
    { idModele: 1, name: "Bianca", price: 500 },
    { idModele: 2, name: "etc", price: 600 }
  ];
```